# Dynamically add <div> in a loop based on variable value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

I have a function that renders news tiles ("cards") that looks like this:

```
 renderNews = <div className={styles["my-Grid-col"] + " " + styles["col-sm12"]+ " " + styles["col-md12"] + " " + styles["col-lg12"] + " " + styles["col-xl12"] + " " + styles["my-document-card-placeholder"] + " " + styles["my-document-card-single-channel"]}>
      <div className={styles["my-Grid-row"]}>
        {cards[this.state.index]}
        {cards[this.state.index + 1]}
        {cards[this.state.index + 2]}
        {cards[this.state.index + 3]}
        {cards[this.state.index + 4]}
        {cards[this.state.index + 5]}
      </div>
    </div>;
```

Problem with above is that number of rows and number of news tiles are hard coded. I want the user to choose number of rows and columns which will be saved in a state.

Lets call them `this.state.columns` and `this.state.row`. Based on these two variables, the output will look differently. For example,
lets say that `this.state.row = 2` and `this.state.columns = 3`, the output will then be:

```
renderNews = <div className={styles["my-Grid-col"] + " " + styles["col-sm12"]+ " " + styles["col-md12"] + " " + styles["col-lg12"] + " " + styles["col-xl12"] + " " + styles["my-document-card-placeholder"] + " " + styles["my-document-card-single-channel"]}>
      <div className={styles["my-Grid-row"]}>
        {cards[this.state.index]}
        {cards[this.state.index + 1]}
        {cards[this.state.index + 2]}
  <div className={styles["my-Grid-row"]}>
        {cards[this.state.index + 3]}
        {cards[this.state.index + 4]}
        {cards[this.state.index + 5]}
      </div>
    </div>;
```

As above shows, as `this.state.row = 2`, two row divs will be created. Additionally, since `this.state.columns = 3`, three news tiles will render between each row.

How can I do a loop that does above - create the divs dynamically based on the value in the two states?

Comment: seems like .map() might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a combination of two nested `for` loops and two nested `map` functions. I have first rewritten your variable `renderNews` to a function. I will break it up into parts to be able to explain it better.

In the beginning, I declare an array as well as an index:

```
  function renderNews() {
    let news = [];
    let cardIndex = 0;
```

I then do a for loop over a before specified number of rows, where I declare a new array to push the column items into in a nested loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  let newRow = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
    newRow.push(cards[cardIndex]);
    cardIndex++;
  }
  news.push(newRow);
}
```

I increment the `cardIndex` to make sure that I don't start in the beginning of the cards array in the next loop. The result of this nested loops is an array of arrays, over which I use two `map` functions to return the result:

```
    return (
      <div
        className={
          styles["my-Grid-col"] +
          " " +
          styles["col-sm12"] +
          " " +
          styles["col-md12"] +
          " " +
          styles["col-lg12"] +
          " " +
          styles["col-xl12"] +
          " " +
          styles["my-document-card-placeholder"] +
          " " +
          styles["my-document-card-single-channel"]
        }
      >
        {news.map((itemArray) => (
          <div className={styles["my-Grid-row"]}>
            {itemArray.map((item) => item)}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

You can check out my full example in a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/XWdOMKN?editors=1111). I hope it is not too confusing.